# Get the html from a website with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get the page data of an other website somewhere on the web with ruby on rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [httparty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to just get the data

Sample code (from [example](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/google.rb)):

```
require File.join(dir, 'httparty')
require 'pp'

class Google
  include HTTParty
  format :html
end

# google.com redirects to www.google.com so this is live test for redirection
pp Google.get('http://google.com')

puts '', '*'*70, ''

# check that ssl is requesting right
pp Google.get('https://www.google.com')
```

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) really excels at parsing that data.. Here's some example code from the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri):

```
url = "http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_constraint=0&ic=48_0&search_query=batman&Find.x=0&Find.y=0&Find=Find"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".item").each do |item|
  title = item.at_css(".prodLink").text
  price = item.at_css(".PriceCompare .BodyS, .PriceXLBold").text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]
  puts "#{title} - #{price}"
  puts item.at_css(".prodLink")[:href]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Net/HTTP` (for example, read [this cheatsheet](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet)):

```
require "net/https"

http = Net::HTTP.new "google.com", 80
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new "/"
response = http.request request

puts response.code
puts response.body
```

Answer (score 4):

[Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) ships in the standard library, that's a plus, but there are  cool higher-level libraries you may take a look at, like [rest-client](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client):

```
RestClient.get('http://example.com/resource', params: {x: "1", y: "2"})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It just may be the ticket for a new project of mine.

Answer (score 3):

I like OpenURI myself if it's just to simply get the content no fuss.

Just add `require 'open-uri'` to the environment and then do `open('http://domain.tld/document.html').read`.